# symfony Invalid credentials memory provider

Tags: php, symfony

Im trying login with user that defined it in memory section but i got error invalid credentials, here my security.yml

```
security:
   encoders:
       Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
   providers:
       in_memory:
           memory:
               users:
                   user:
                       password: 1234
                       roles: 'ROLE_USER'
                   root:
                       password: 1234
                       roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'

   firewalls:
       dev:
           pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
           security: false
       main:
           pattern: ^/
           anonymous: true
           form_login:
               login_path: login
               check_path: login
           logout:
               path: logout
               target: homepage
   access_control:
       - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
       - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

so what the problem? :|

Comment: Are you missing indentation for all keys under security? It seems `security` is at same level as `encoders`, `providers` and so on, and they're all should be under security perhaps?

Comment: Can you confirm your indentation is correct like @Mr_KoKa mentioned?

Comment: its ok indentation is ok in main file, just when paste it seems this

Comment: @MosiIsp Try to set `provider: in_memory` under `main`

Comment: @Mr_KoKa i got this error : The service "security.authentication.provider.dao.main" has a dependency on a non-existent service "security.user.provider.concrete.memory".

Comment: version of symfony is 3.3

Comment: shame on me :) name of inputs in my login form must be `_username` and `_password`